# R create column based on specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have iris dataframe, I want a function that create/replace a new/existing column  by combining others, this function has 2 parameters : name of the new column and names of columns to combine.

for example I want to combine Petal.Width and Species :
I tried :

```
func <- function(data, names, column_names){
data <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(column_names), names = paste0(column_names))
}

iris <- func(iris, "Petal.Width", c("Petal.Width","Species"))
```

Honestly I don't know how to deal with variables that must be considered like names.

The result should be :

```
iris$Petal.Width <- paste0(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species)
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MrFlick yes, the second argument "Petal.Width" is the column that I want to create or replace if it exists already, and the third argument are columns that I want to combine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rlang::syms` to convert your character values to symbols. And then can use `!!!` and `:=` to inject them into the call

```
func <- function(data, names, column_names){
  column_names <- syms(column_names)
  data %>% mutate("{names}" := paste0(!!!column_names))
}

func(iris, "Petal.Width", c("Petal.Width","Species"))
```

For more suggestions on creating your own functions that use `dplyr`, see the [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) guide

Comment: thx! exactly what I want! but what are differences between !! and !!!? and why using := instead of =?

Comment: You can read more about injecting at: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html